# Javascript: adding bold text dynamically within paragraph

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a text to web page and some of it as bold dynamically through Javascript. But the bold text moves to new line and not within same line. I would like it to be at same line. Here is the output:

[image]

[image]

My code is:

```
var paraNode = document.createElement('p');
paraNode.className = "card card-body";
var textToAppend = " Passenger Revenue for " + month + " " + year + ": " + String(totalValue).bold();
paraNode.innerHTML = textToAppend
notebookElement.appendChild(paraNode)
```

I have also tried using `<strong>` tag replacing `.bold()` but the result is same.

Comment: hmm works for me when I try it, want to see if you can reproduce it in a codepen?

Comment: Yes, please that will be great.

Comment: @Hannan [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrgWoM) -- seems to work

Answer (score 4):

I tried and looks fine I think `CSS` could be the Issue.

```js
var paraNode = document.createElement('p');
paraNode.className = "card card-body";
var textToAppend = " Passenger Revenue for " + String("34").bold();
paraNode.innerHTML = textToAppend
document.body.appendChild(paraNode)
```